# Making slideToggle() elements collapsed by default in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a set of divs that I want to make `collapsible/expandable` using jQuery's `slideToggle()` method. How do I make all of these divs collapsed by default? I'd like to avoid explicitly calling `slideToggle()` on each element during/after page rendering.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You will have to assign a style: display:none to these layers, so that they are not displayed before javascript rendering. Then you can call slideToggle() without problems. Example:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .text{display:none}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {    
        $('span.more').click(function() {
            $('p:eq(0)').slideToggle();
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
</script>

<body>              
      <p class="text">
          I am using jquery <br/>
          I am using jquery <br/>
          I am using jquery <br/>
          I am using jquery <br/>
          I am using jquery <br/>
          I am using jquery <br/>           
      </p>
      <span class="more">show</span>
```

Comment: This'd cause issues for people who have Javascript disabled but CSS enabled.  They won't be able to see your content!

Comment: I know, but the question implied that Craig didn't want to use javascript to do the show/hide action, so the only alternative is stylesheets. Anyway, surely if he is using javascript in some manner, his code will be totally inaccessible for screen readers etc... I work with this type of exigences

Comment: strager is right, but in this particular case I don't care so much about +CSS -JS (the site will have bigger problems then this particular page if that's the case).

Answer (score 14):

You can start your elements with style="display: none;" and slideToggle() will take it from there.

Answer (score 13):

you probably can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').hide();
});
```

Comment: The benefit of this version is, if jquery disappears, you default to both being shown.

Comment: Problem is you get FOUC issues.

Answer (score 2):

Applying a CSS style behind the scenes will, as stated before, cause complications for users with scripts disabled. A way around this is to declare your element hidden as Anne said, or by defining your CSS in your script as a function to be altered, not as styling for the page (to keep structure, style and function separate) and then using the toggleClass function of the script or the custom effect hide functions defined by jQuery.